# Python database result set into json

Tags: python, json

I want to convert database result set into json.

I used `json.dumps()` it converts as `"{key:\"value\"}"` but I don't want quotes around the string and backlashes. How I can convert as `{key:"value"}`

Here is my code.

**Model**

```
class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payload = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

**View**

```
data = json.dumps(list(DeviceDetail.objects.filter(deviceId=deviceId).values('deviceId','payload')))

HttpResponse(data)
```

**Response**:

```
[
  {
    "deviceId":"10",
   "payload":"{key:\"value\"}"
  },
  {
   "deviceId":"10",
   "payload":"{key:\"value\"}"
  },
  {
   "deviceId":"10",
   "payload":"\"{key:\\\"value\\\"}\""
  },
  {
   "deviceId":"10",
   "payload":"{key:\"value\"}"
  }
]
```

Without `json.dumps()`

```
{'deviceId': u'10', 'payload': u'{key:"value"}'}
```

Comment: Did you encode twice perhaps? What is your exact code?

Comment: And that is *all* the code? Where do you see the wrongly quoted values?

Comment: @MartijnPieters While rendering http response

Comment: And none of your `deviceId` and `payload` columns are themselves JSON values? Can we see actual input and output please?

Comment: Your payload values are **already** JSON strings and are encoded again.

Comment: You appear to have a *triple* encoded string in there too: `"{key:\\\"value\\\"}\"` albeit none of your keys have proper quoting. You probably omitted the quoting in posting, I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `payload` values are encoded *strings* and these are encoded as JSON strings again.

If you wanted those to be JSON objects instead, you'll first have to decode them to Python objects:

```
data = json.dumps([
    {'deviceId': dd['deviceId'], 'payload': json.loads(dd['payload'])}
    for dd in DeviceDetail.objects.filter(deviceId=deviceId).values('deviceId','payload')
])
```

where I assume that the values are actual JSON-encoded values.

If they are *not* JSON encoded values, then it is unclear what you want. As strings, the JSON encoding for them is entirely correct and quotes in the values *must* be escaped using backslashes.

Comment: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: Then your `payload` strings are not JSON strings. In which case you probably need them to be strings anyway and the back-slashes are *entirely correct*. Why do you want the backslashes gone in the first place?

Comment: I want pure json object, Front end developer are not able to parse if it is string

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: Then you have a problem, because it appears your `payload` string is **not** valid JSON. Where did it come from? Your sample data is accurately reflecting the contents?

Comment: JSON is also coming from front end, I am storing it in string field in mongodb.

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: It'd be easier if the front-end could be fixed to produce valid JSON instead.

Comment: I think the problem is with `CharField` it converts json object into string

Comment: No, JSON is text. Always. The database merely stored that text. The input was already incorrect.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I just make sure that input is proper, it worked fine.